# cron job on centOS 6.5

Tags: linux, bash, centos, crontab

I have used these 2 references to insert a new crontab entry.

[redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Automating_System_Tasks.html)

[ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

I have created a new bash file and moved it to /usr/bin.  That sh file has execute permissions for the root user and the admin group.  The bash file just echos a line to a log file and then calls a java program.  I have tested the sh file as root, manually.  It runs fine.  My crontab entry looks like this...

```
 @hourly      /usr/bin/foo.blah.sh
```

It's supposed to run at the top of every hour.  The echo statement is not getting printed to the log file so I don't think crond is calling it at all.  Also, when I visually monitor processes in "top", the job never appears.  I have run "service crond status" to verify the cron daemon is running.  The documentation says that restarting the daemon is not necessary.  What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output when you list your crontab file: crontab -l

Comment: "no crontab for root"   What does that mean?

Comment: @bwfrieds It means that there is no user-specific crontab file for the user named root. Crontabs can be user-specific or system-wide; I think you have made a system-wide one. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually say where the crontab entry is, but based on your comment that `crontab -l` outputs `no crontab for root`, I would hazard a guess that you have added a file under one of the /etc/cron.* directories, which contains files corresponding to various cron jobs. This answer assumes that that is the case.

Those files have a format that is slightly different from the user-specific crontab that you edit through `crontab -e`. Specifically, **they include a username field** just before the command, which is not included in the user-specific crontab (which at least on my system are stored under /var/spool/cron/crontabs, but please don't abuse that information; the exact location is an implementation detail of the cron daemon you happen to be running, and you should use the documented interfaces for managing those files).

As a result, **you should change**

```
@hourly      /usr/bin/foo.blah.sh
```

to

```
@hourly user /usr/bin/foo.blah.sh
```

where `user` is the name of the user account to run the script as. It should then run fine.

I really encourage you to not run cron jobs as `root` unless you must; doing anything as the superuser is always a security risk. If possible, give the script its own account with restricted access. (This is the principle of least privilege; least, that is, that is required for it to do its job.) As a general rule, you should place [system-local files into /usr/local](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#USRLOCALLOCALHIERARCHY) to avoid clashes with the system package manager; additionally, to avoid confusion, don't place things in any bin directory that need root privileges to work, use sbin instead.

Comment: +1 for separate user account for automated tasks

Answer (score 0):

In the past, when adding scripts to cron, I always led the line with sh, like so:

```
@hourly    sh /usr/bin/foo.blah.sh
```